# How to add FileSystem disk Drive space to another Disk

Tags: disk-management

My File System Drive is around 50 gb, and i want to add around 20 gb to another drive which contains files, how can i achieve that,
are there any tools or commands to do

Comment: So you want to shrink your file system drive to 30 GB and add the remaining space to another drive? Do you use LVM?

Comment: yes, i want to do that, but whats LVM

Comment: LVM enables dynamic resizing of Linux Partitions, which means you can even resize the operating system partition. It asks you if you want to use it on Elementary OS installer.

Comment: You can get gparted (a partition manager) from the AppCentre, that might help you, it should at least help explain what options are available to you. If you are doing things that you're unsure of though, best back-up first.

Comment: @SamMorrowDrums while installing gparted it gives, unmet dependency error

Comment: You may have messed up your dependency chain with additional ppa's try advice from here http://askubuntu.com/q/616377/649018

Comment: i tried all this many times, please can u come over team viewer and help me

Comment: unmet dependencies is causing a lot of problem to mine works